# How to avoid circular imports when using Python type hints

Tags: python, python-3.x, design-patterns, circular-dependency, typing

I'm trying to figure out what would be the best solution to avoid circular imports in a situation where I'm using `Protocol` and type hints. The problem is the following:

I have some storage targets that in the push method receives and Event.

```
from typing import Protocol
from event import Event


class StorageProtocol(Protocol):
    def push(self, event: Event):
        ...

class StoragePostgres(StorageProtocol):
    def push(self, event: Event):
        """pushes Event to Postgres"""
        pass

class StorageS3(StorageProtocol):
    def push(self, event: Event):
        """pushes Event to S3"""
        pass
```

And I have some event that has a function to store itself in something that implements the Protocol `StorageProtocol`.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from storage import StorageProtocol


@dataclass
class Event:
    id: str
    start_datetime: str
    end_datetime: str
    
    def push(self, storage: StorageProtocol):
        storage.push(self)
```

This results in a circular import error because the `storage.py` imports Event and `event.py` imports StorageProtocol.

I'm aware of using some approaches like the following

1. `from __future__ import annotations`
2. `from typing import TYPE_CHECKING`
3. Importing only within the class
4. Using some if statements to avoid import at run time
5. Remove type hint
6. Using type hints in quotes

But none of them seem like a good way to keep the code clean. What am I missing to not figure out how to make this simple example clean?

Comment: Uses e.g. `def push(self, storage: 'StorageProtoco'l):` without importing the module. So a delayed type checking

Comment: That's the idea number 6. My point is: if I'm having a circular import problem I think I probably have a design problem as well. I would rather solve the design problem than come up with tricks. But I can't find what is the problem in design here.

Comment: I don't think 1, 3 or 6 will help this case, prefer to avoid 5, and 2+4 would be used together (i.e. `if TYPE_CHECKING: from storage import StorageProtocol` ...I'm not 100% sure this avoids circular import error though). A typical way to fix these kind of circular import issues is to move the common item (i.e. `StorageProtocol`) into a separate module that they both import from.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I don't think that will work. Quoted-string type annotations aren't a replacement for imports, they are "forward references" to types defined later in the same file, i.e. they defer resolution of the type name.

Comment: "A typical way to fix these kind of circular import issues is to move the common item (i.e. StorageProtocol) into a separate module that they both import from." - this wouldn't solve the problem because `StorageProtocol` needs to import `Event` for the type hinting in `def push(self, event: Event)`

Comment: "and 2+4 would be used together" - I was also thinking about `if False: from storage import StorageProtocol`

Comment: The real solution it is to redesign the classes. Why storage need to know about event? Do it independent. Or why event must know storage? So decouple storage from event, e.g. moving it in an event handler. Decoupling helps also on testing, but it requires rethinking the program structure. Or in storage uses a new class: Item. And let item to have a method to get data (so you can derive independently EventItem.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I like that idea and I agree that `StorageProtocol` shouldn't need to know what objects to store but be generalized. But I fail to understand what exactly should it have as parameter and when the function to `push an event to a storage` should be. Each Storage (postgres, S3) has different implementation and can store different data from `Event`. In the Postgres case it will be in a specific table with specific fields. So where should I put these specific implementations?

Comment: It depends on design. An other classical solution: you create a class EventData just as container of interface data. And you define inside Event. Storage know just about Eventdata. It is the "token" both know about it, but no need for Storage or Event to know the methods and internal of the other. Or check Gamma et al. about Design Patterns: there will be other pattern to be used (your design is common)

Comment: **Runtime** circular imports are a symptom of a design problem. Circular imports which are required to use static typing annotations are *not* a design problem; `from __future__ import annotations` & `if typing.TYPE_CHECKING` can be seen as Python's alternative to C and C++'s header files. The alternative is a giant module, which becomes very difficult to manage.

Comment: It's not entirely clear that `StorageProtocol` and its subclasses need to be in a separate module. If they are only used for event handling, it would make sense to add them to `event.py`. (There's a difference between a "big" module and a "too big" module.)